# SMS Inbox not refreshing

Tags: android

I write down a program to read/write SMS from/to inbox. The operation of read/write always successful. After writing SMSs I am getting the inbox empty until I send or receive normal SMS.

Please let me know how to **refresh the Inbox messages programmatically**.

Comment: The SMS database is managed by the SMS app, so you'll need an app-specific solution here. Is it the stock Android app? HTC's version? Somebody else's?

Comment: I tested app on HTC tatto and Samsung Galaxy 3...result is same..Not refreshing the inbox.