# How to get unread SMS when just receive it?

Tags: android

I'm building a unread SMS relay application. There are phone A and B, when A receives a SMS and no one read it, my application relay it to B. But I find that when A receives a SMS, there is a system notification display.  My `ContentObserver`'s `onChange()` method only called until I disappear the notification. What should I do to get the unread SMS when receive it?

ContentObserver:

```
public NewIncomingContentObserver(Handler handler, Application 

application) {
    super(handler);
    this.mApplication = application;
  }

  @Override
  public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    System.out.println(selfChange);
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
    mMessageListener.OnReceived(this.getSmsInfo(uri, mApplication));
  }

  /**
   * get the newest SMS
   */
  private SmsInfo getSmsInfo(Uri uri, Application application) {
    ...
  }

  public interface MessageListener {
    public void OnReceived(SmsInfo smsInfo);
  }

  public void setOnReceivedMessageListener(
          MessageListener messageListener) {
    this.mMessageListener = messageListener;
  }
}
```

Service:

```
public class SmsListenerService extends Service {
  public static final String URI = "content://sms/inbox";

  public SmsListenerService() {
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Register observer
    NewIncomingContentObserver smsContentObserver =
            new NewIncomingContentObserver(new Handler(), getApplication());

    this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver
            (Uri.parse(URI), true, smsContentObserver);

    smsContentObserver.setOnReceivedMessageListener(new NewIncomingContentObserver.MessageListener() {
      @Override
      public void OnReceived(SmsInfo smsInfo) {
        System.out.println(smsInfo);
      }
    });
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example borrowed from (https://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin), the example is a phonegap plugin but you can still use it:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";

    // This broadcast boolean is used to continue or not the message broadcast
    // to the other BroadcastReceivers waiting for an incoming SMS (like the native SMS app)
    private boolean broadcast = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

        // Get the SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
           // Get received SMS Array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);

            for (int i=0; i < smsExtra.length; i++)
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);

                    String formattedMsg = sms.getOriginatingAddress() + ">" + sms.getMessageBody();

            }

            // If the plugin is active and we don't want to broadcast to other receivers
            if (!broadcast) {
                this.abortBroadcast();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

And in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Is BroadcastReceiver a better way? I found three ways to get SMS: BroadcastReceiver, ContentObserver and Loader. But I have no idea which one is more effective.

Answer (score 0):

[SMS Inbox not refereshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163628/sms-inbox-not-refereshing)

I think SMS inbox is managed by specific SMS app. So listen new SMS through `content://sms/inbox` is a SMS-app-specific solution in my application. @Niels 's answer maybe a better solution.